# Python CSV data import to table like object

Tags: python, csv, statistics

I have data from csv:
time, meas, meas2
15:10, 10, 0.3
15:22, 12, 0.4
15:30, 4

So every row can contain different number of data, less or equal to number of columns in first row.

I am writing some simple stats app. But for one graph I need for example sum of data in column with name meas. But for the second graph I would like to filter this data by the time.
Is there any ready-to-get- class with some kind of object to utilise getting data from columns or rows depending on need?
Or I just need to keep data in rows and calculate input for the 1st graph on the fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the pandas library.  The docs can be found here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/

You can run `pip install pandas` to install it.

The DataFrame is the basic pandas object that you work with.  You can read your data in like this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
>>> df
    time   meas   meas2
0  15:10     10     0.3
1  15:22     12     0.4
2  15:30      4     NaN

>>> df['meas'].sum()
26
```

At this point `time` will be string values.  To convert them to time objects you could do this (there may be a better way):

```
>>> df['time'] = [x.time() for x in pd.to_datetime(df['time'])]
```

Now to filter on time... Let's say you want everything after line 1.

```
>>> time1 = df['time'][1]
>>> df['time'] > time1
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: time, dtype: bool
```

You can use the boolean expression to filter your DataFrame like this:

```
>>>  df[df['time'] > time0]
       time  meas  meas2
2  15:30:00     4    NaN
```

Comment: Since this comment is more detailed I have marked it as answer. Thank You, that's amazing answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little confusing, but it sounds like a Pandas DataFrame would be helpful. You can read csv files right into them.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('your_csv_file.csv')
```

Of course you may need to get familiar with pandas for this to be useful.